# Install python packages for specific python version

Tags: 14.04, package-management, python

I understand that in Ubuntu 14.04, you have access to both python 2.7.6 and python 3.4.0. When getting python packages through the command line, how do I make sure that I am installing packages meant for python 2.7.6 and not for python 3.4.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `apt-file` to find out the package name. For example if you want to install the right version of reportlab use:

```
apt-file -l search reportlab
```

On my system this produces:

```
gambas3-gb-report
python-mvpa2
python-pdfrw
python-pisa
python-renderpm
python-renderpm-dbg
python-reportlab
python-reportlab-accel
python-reportlab-accel-dbg
python-reportlab-doc
python3-renderpm
python3-renderpm-dbg
python3-reportlab
python3-reportlab-accel
python3-reportlab-accel-dbg
```

It is fair to assume that package python-reportlab is the 2.7 version and package python3-reportlab is the python 3.x version. If however you want to check that further you can use `dpkg -L python-reportlab` — this will list the package contents and you will see that the files are in `/usr/lib/python2.7`.

Unfortunately the `dpkg -L` works only on installed packages so if you want to check it before you install the package you will have to use the [Ubuntu packages web interface](http://packages.ubuntu.com). Once you open a [package details page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python3-reportlab) you can click on [list of files](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/python3-reportlab/filelist) and find out whether the files are in `/usr/lib/python2.7` or in `/usr/lib/python3`.